# how to cumsum unique items by date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
a = [
 ('xyz1','2018-01-30','Error'),
 ('xyz1','2018-01-30','Error'),
 ('xyz1','2018-01-31','OK'),
 ('xyz2','2018-01-31','OK'),
 ('abc123','2018-02-04','Error'),
 ('abc123','2018-02-05','OK'),
 ]

df =pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['sn','date','status'])

print(df.groupby('date').sn.nunique())
date
2018-01-30    1
2018-01-31    2
2018-02-04    1
2018-02-05    1
Name: sn, dtype: int64

print(df.groupby('date').sn.nunique().cumsum())
date
2018-01-30    1
2018-01-31    3
2018-02-04    4
2018-02-05    5
Name: sn, dtype: int64
```

but actually, for start date 2018-01-30 to date 2018-02-04, they are totally 4 unique sn: xyz1,xyz2,abc123, so the expected cumsum value is 3, not 4, so using the pandas cumsum is not a good way for this purpose.

How to get the result what I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 4 is expected (1 + 2 + 1 = 4).

To complete your task, you may need [`pandas.Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html).

```
df['not_dup'] = 1 - df.sn.duplicated()  #Indicator that 'sn' is not duplicated
df.groupby('date').not_dup.sum().cumsum()
```

Output:

```
# date
# 2018-01-30    1
# 2018-01-31    2
# 2018-02-04    3
# 2018-02-05    3
# Name: not_dup, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me.  pandas.Series.duplicated  is so useful!